# Why my trailing zero at two decimal places is not printed out?

Tags: php

I'm using a class from Github for string manipulation to be printed out on the thermal printer. Here is the class

```
class item
{
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $dollarSign;

    public function __construct($name = '', $price = '', $dollarSign = false)
    {
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> price = $price;
        $this -> dollarSign = $dollarSign;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $rightCols = 10;
        $leftCols = 38;
        if ($this -> dollarSign) {
            $leftCols = $leftCols / 2 - $rightCols / 2;
        }
        $left = str_pad($this -> name, $leftCols) ;
6y
        $sign = ($this -> dollarSign ? 'RM ' : '');
        $right = str_pad($sign . $this -> price, $rightCols, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return "$left$right\n";
    }
}
```

The problem here is, I do still get the price printed without trailing 0 for example, input is 4.50 and the return result (return "$left$right\n";) from the class is only 4.5. Same goes for input 6.00, and I do only get 6. Anyone can share on the trailing zero after decimal had gone? without using this class, i can successfully printer out 4.50 and 6.00. Only after using the class i see this problem.

Comment: STR_PAD_LEFT are you sure?

Comment: Yes, just to make sure the number is at left of the paper.

Answer (score 0):

Guarantee to always show cents after dollar(s) amount

```
sprintf('%0.2f', $the_price);
```

Comment: Hi Steph, i would like to print to the thermal printer as a string as i undersand that sprintf is already aprinting command. Is it the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), it will guarantee two decimal places.

```
number_format($the_price, 2);
```

Comment: yes it did, but once using the class as the price input, the trailing 0 is gone.